# Argument of Riemann zeta function for point in the strip

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, asymptotics, riemann-zeta

In

H.L. Montgomery, Extreme values of the Riemann zeta function, Comment. Math. Helvetici 52 (1977) 511-518

it was shown in the Corollary on page 511-512 that
$$\arg \zeta (s)=\Omega_{\pm}((\log t)^{1-\sigma}(\log \log t)^{1-\sigma})$$
for $1/2<\sigma<1$ and large $t$ as $t \to \infty$. Here, what does the symbol $\Omega{\pm}$ mean? Also, are there any "O" results (i.e.,$\arg \zeta (s)=O(\cdots)$) for $\arg \zeta (s)$ for $1/2<\sigma<1$ and large $t$ as $t \to \infty$?

Comment: $f (x) =\Omega(g(x))$ means that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ does not tend to zero. See the Hardy-Littlewood notation in the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) article for the Landau symbols "Big Omega" and "Big O". I also think that you should review the symbol reference in Montgomery's paper. And $\Omega_{\pm}$ is $\Omega_R$ and $\Omega_L$, see the wikipedia article.

Answer (score 2):

As in the comments, $f(x)=\Omega_+(g(x))$ usually means that $\limsup_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}>0$ and $f(x)=\Omega_-(g(x))$ usually means that $\liminf_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<0$. The symbol $\Omega_\pm$ means that both inequalities above holds.

For your second question, yes we have that, assuming the RH

$\arg \zeta(s)=O(\frac{\log t}{\log\log t})$, for $\Re(s)\geq\frac{1}{2}$, as $t \to\infty$.

Unconditionally, we have for $\frac{1}{2}<\sigma<1$

$\arg\zeta(s)=O(\log t),$ as $t\to\infty$.

For a reference you can check the classic: Multiplicative number theory. I. Classical theory.
Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, 97. From Montgomery and Vaughan.